# Can we append App_DLLs value?

Tags: dll, dll-injection

I have a situation where two application are injecting dlls and updating HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs with its value.

As App_DLLs is REG_SZ type registry. So we can have only value of AppInit_DLLs which is making only application running at one time.

Is there any way that I can append the value of App_DLLs so that both application can use their respective dlls and run concurrently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working with the AppInit_DLLs registry value](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197571)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but Is there any way by which we can append values in the AppInit_DLLs which allows both application to run smoothly.

Comment: @DNamto - yes read the article - "The AppInit_DLLs value has type "REG_SZ." This value has to specify a NULL-terminated string of DLLs that is delimited by spaces or by commas"